# Whats the best way to deliver TFS build status notifications to the team?

Tags: tfs, msbuild, build-automation, continuous-integration

I like the status email sent by TFS's alerts mechanism when a build breaks.
However I would like to send such an email to the entire team and not rely on the team to subscribe to the alert...

Having a hard time producing a nice and detailed enough message by myself when overriding the "OnBuildBreak" and using the MSBuildCommunityTasks EMail task.

Is there a way to force a TFS alert to be sent to a list of emails?
Can you recommend of a way to send such status notifications?

Comment: For updated answers, see this question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32776840/no-build-notifications-with-vs-2015

Answer (score 6):

You could try.

[Brian the build bunny](http://www.woodwardweb.com/gadgets/000434.html)

:-)

Answer (score 6):

The Team Build Tray Notification tool what is included in the [TFS 2008 Power Tools](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=00803636-1D16-4DF1-8A3D-EF1AD4F4BBAB&displaylang=en) is very useful for this.

[image: Build Notification Tray tool]

See [Buck Hodges' blog for screenshots and more information](http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/archive/2007/09/21/build-notification-tray-applet-power-tool-for-tfs-2008.aspx).

Comment: Too bad it is broken after installing TFS 2008 SP1. It should be fixed in the November release of the power tools though

Comment: Yes, it seems to be (at least) badly unreliable. Often does not update any more until you close and restart it. Really too bad.

Comment: It is extremely unreliable and if there are constant builds going you never know the actual build is broke.

Answer (score 5):

I don't want to dig up an old topic, but for those that stumble upon it two years late (like me), this is built into TFS 2010 now.

Answer (score 4):

Set up an email alias for the team on the mail server, and enter this when subscribing to the mail.

Try the [Team Foundation Server Event Subscription Tool](http://www.codeplex.com/tfseventsubscription).
This allows you to send emails to any address when any TFS event occurs.

Answer (score 3):

[Brian the Build bunny](http://www.woodwardweb.com/gadgets/000434.html) is nice but the Nabaztagtag WiFi Rabbit bunny is pretty expensive and is currently out of stock.

The Team Build Tray Notification that comes with TFS is ok, but:

- It's damn slow and polling is not configurable
- It's too easy to miss the build being broken for projects you care about
- Doesn't support different actions for different projects (e.g. show a modal dialog for project #1, but just show a short tray alert for project #2)
- Doesn't support different triggers for different people (e.g. show notifications for just me on project #1 or anyone on project #2)
- No information on what broke the build (e.g. compiler error, unit test, integration test)
- No audible notification if system's on mute
- No last build times

So there's an open source project on Google Code that runs in the tray that's available on Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/siren-of-shame/. That project can work independently but it's designed to work with a [USB Siren](http://www.sirenofshame.com/) that is available for sale.

Answer (score 2):

I generally like the [TFS Build Status Tray](http://raquila.com/software/team-foundation-server-build-notification-tray/) by Rob Aquila. Be sure to get the 1.0.1 Beta, as this lets you easily specify the projects to watch using a bit of GUI and also has a notify icon that changes color, so you only need to open the actual build status list when the icon turns red. The 1.0 version had a fixed icon, and only notify toasts in the corner of your screen.

There is also [a version of the same tool](http://raquila.com/software/team-foundation-server-build-notification-screen/) that is meant to be shown full screen on a wall mounted display for instance.

Comment: +1 this is a great tool to remain open on a second monitor for example

Answer (score 1):

The July release of [TFS 2008 PowerTools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/tfs2008/bb980963.aspx) adds an "Alert Editor" to Team Explorer.  Adding Alerts is a breeze.  It has a query tool similar to the Query tool.

Answer (score 0):

In my mind, a open source project named 'Web Deployment Projects' can do this. your can search for it.