# How can I set up a fun build notification via TFS 2010?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-automation, x10

I've been trying to find a guide on how to get Team Foundation Server to turn on a lava lamp or traffic light to indicate the status of the build. I want to set up something that's visible right across the office so there's some peer pressure to encourage developers not to break the build; but I also want it to be fun.

There's a lot of examples for CruiseControl that use X.10 devices which seems like a good way to go. But I can't find anything similar for TFS. I'm sure that somebody must be doing this somewhere...?

Using X.10 has one problem in that it requires a serial port - but our TFS is completely virtualised in a data centre somewhere. Maybe there is some way to trigger the traffic light via an email?

Any advice appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point I had stumbled upon [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Is32fWJJA-I) youtube-video, where Martin Woodward presents Brian, the funky TFS-build bunny. Might be worth checking.  
It might also be worth checking [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37997/whats-the-best-way-to-deliver-tfs-build-status-notifications-to-the-team) SO post.

Answer (score 3):

The TFS have got a nice API for getting the status of recent builds. You can use the API and design your own fun system.

Also take a look at:

- [TFS Build Monitor](http://buildmonitor.codeplex.com/)
- [TFS Build Light](http://tfsbuildlight.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 2):

The TFS API's are terrible they're a pain to do yourself.  You could start with this open source project on Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/siren-of-shame/.  That project is designed to work with a couple of different build servers, but everything is broken out, so you could start with the TFS 2010 project (TfsServices.csproj).  Or if you don't want to do it all yourself that project is designed to work with a USB Siren that they sell (see http://www.sirenofshame.com/).